# Closing JFrame with Button

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jpanel

I am currently using Eclipse's drag and Drop feature, I have one application window which comes with JFrame by default and is able to `setVisible(false);` but my other frames/panel/window I have created with JPanel and with extending JFrame.

Because of `extend` I am unable to `setVisible(false or true);` it has no effect at all on the window it still remains true.

My code :

```
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LibrarianMenu frame = new LibrarianMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public LibrarianMenu() {
    setTitle("Librarian");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 385, 230);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    .
    .
    . so on
```

Here I am trying to execute my button:

```
 btnLogout.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LibrarianMenu frame = new LibrarianMenu();
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
```

Any solutions for it?

Comment: Please post a compilable example because there isn't even a class definition in your code. Either way you need to call `setVisible(false)` on the same reference you called `setVisible(true)` on, not on a reference that refers a newly created object.

Comment: Don't create LibrarianMenu in the onClick, create it as field in your main class and then use setVisible to false. You are creatin another LibrarianMenu when the button is clicked, so the first one persists.

Comment: `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(btnLogout).setVisible(false)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because every time you press the button you create a new instance of that frame. Here is your code updated :

```
static LibrarianMenu frame ;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new LibrarianMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the logout button event should be like this :

```
btnLogout.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @nix `static` is one of those solutions which "looks" good, but which will lead you down a dark ally, beat you senseless and steal your wallet, all in order, better to be avoided

Answer (score 3):

Because you're creating the frame inside the Runnable, its scope is limited to that of the runnable. Try declaring the variable outside of the runnable, then initializing it within the runnable, like so:

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private LibrarianMenu frame;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new LibrarianMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then setvisible to false without declaring a new instance of LibrarianMenu:

```
btnLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           frame.setVisible(false);
     }
});
```

Comment: @nix If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks :)