# How to close jframe panel or window

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

I have 2 frames/windows, I have Exit button on window 2, an from window 1 I launch window 2 and then exit it i.e `setVisible(false);`

When I execute window 2 I can easily click button exit and hide the current window, however when I launch window 2 from window 1, and then click exit button I get `NullPointerException` Error. then I instantiated it in the beginning with static and this error was gone, however the window 2 is not being closed/hidden its still there with no effect of button.

**Window 1 code:**

```
package com.my.jlms;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class LibrarianMenu extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private static LibrarianMenu frame;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new LibrarianMenu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public LibrarianMenu() {
    setTitle("Librarian");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 385, 230);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnPasswd = new JButton("Change Pass");
    btnPasswd.setBounds(202, 76, 146, 39);
    contentPane.add(btnPasswd);


    btnPasswd.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ChangePwd framee = new ChangePwd();
                    framee.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

}

}
```

**Window 2 Code:**

```
package com.my.jlms;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ChangePwd extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private static ChangePwd frame = new ChangePwd();;

private JButton btnExit;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new ChangePwd();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public ChangePwd() {
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Password!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 266, 154);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(20, 80, 89, 30);
    contentPane.add(btnExit);


    btnExit.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
}
```

}

Is there a solution I can set window 2 to hide ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing JFrame with Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739800/closing-jframe-with-button)

Comment: It looks like you answered "Thank you. solved!" on the duplicate topic, one hour ago..

Comment: You've got a lot of instantiation of JFrames going on in that second Window, statically and from a main method, as well as from Window1. Get rid of all that and just use setVisible(true) instead of frame.setVisible(true). You don't need that frame reference at all.

Comment: @Berger hi, its different not duplicate. if you read my questions and compare they both are different. That focuses on (this) i.e current window, however here I am trying from another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating your frame, as your class, and not on the object `frame`, but you hide the frame which represents the object `frame`.

Change this line (in your actionListener's `actionPerformed()` method):

```
frame.setVisible(false);
```

to:

```
setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispose function for the purpose.[see how dispose works.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close a JFrame, you could use the `dispose()` method.

Example:

```
public void actionPerformer(ActionEvent e)
{ 
  if(e.getSource().equals(closeFrameButton)
     {
        dispose();  //This will close the current JFrame
      }
}
```

NOTE: this is different to `System.exit(0);`. Using this will close the Java virtual machine. if you just want to close the frame, use `dispose()`